# How can I determine if a file I want to read from actually exists?

Tags: java, stream, inputstream

I'm learning Java, and I'm trying to write a program that can read from a `.ser` file, which I've already created with a `writeTo()` method.

I want to know a given file exists in the system before I tell the program to read from it.

My code looks like this:

```
public boolean readFromSerializedFile(String fileName){
    FileInputStream fileInStream = null;
    ObjectInputStream objectInStream = null;

    try{
        fileInStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);  
        objectInStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInStream);
```

Is there a simple way I can determine if the file with the name of the parameter exists in the root directory (or wherever else specified)?

Comment: Doesn't the File class have a method that would directly solve this, `exists()`?

Comment: Have you looked at the API first? That seems a better use of your time and ours, rather than using us as a substitute for this.

Comment: If he is stuck in FIS, then the appropriate solution is not easily found.

Comment: When you try to access the file with the `FileInputStream`, it will check if the file exists for you, if it doesn't it will throw a `FileNotFoundException` (that you should handle). More info: [Class FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [File.exists()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) method.

Let's suppose you want to know if file `abc.xml` exists. The following code illustrates how to do it.

```
final File file = new File ("abc.xml");
final boolean exists = file.exists ();
System.out.println ("abc.xml " + (exists ? "exists" : "does not exist"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Others mentioned File.exists, but if you are learning Java and probably using Java SE 7, I recommend to use the new NIO File API instead:

```
Files.exists(Paths.get(filename));
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29

Also note that Oracle's Java Tutorial is quite useful to learn the standard Java APIs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Using java.io.File
...
String path = "C:\test.txt";
File f = new File(path);
if(f.exists())
```

Comment: If you created f on the line above, obviously it will exist, right?

Comment: This creates a java.io.File object.  It doesn't create a file on disk.    I can enter any path, that doesn't mean the file exists on the machine.  f.exists() tells whether the file at the given path actually exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the `java.io.FileNotFoundException`, which will be thrown in the case scenario you described.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FileReader br = new FileReader(file);

   if(br.ready())
    return;
   else
    System.exit(1);
```